# Spaces whose interiors of retracts is a base of the topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, hausdorff-spaces, separation-axioms

**Definition**:   topological space $\ X\ $ is   r-basic $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ the interiors of retracts of $\ X\ $ form a topological base of $\ X.$

**Main question**: Are r-basic spaces mentioned in any literature?

**Questions**:

1. Does there exist a Hausdorff space that is not r-basic? [closed]
2. Does there exist a a non-metric r-basic Hausdorff space? [closed]
3. Do connectivity components inherit the r-basic property? In other words, is there an r-basic space that is not locally connected?
4. If so, what is the largest natural class of spaces known to you that are r-basic? [now: topological manifolds]

**Answers**

1. Yes

At first any r-basic Hausdorff space is regularly because in a Hudsorff space, a retract is closed.

Second, let S be a property of topological spaces inherited by quotient spaces. Then any space that is S but not locally S is not r-basic. In particular, S = "linear connectivity", S = "connectivity" provide a many examples of non-r-basic spaces ([KP Hart's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/408468/148161))

2. All zero-dimensional spaces, totally ordered sets with the order topology, and arbitrary products of r-basic spaces are r-basic, but these spaces are usually non-metrizable (JosephVanName's comments)
3. [open]
4. Topological manifolds is r-basic (implying Hausdorff and second countability, of course)
   Proof. For a given point, take a neighborhood whose closure is a closed ball. A closed ball is an absolute retract, therefore we have built a retract whose interior contains a given point.

Comment: A zero-dimensional space is a Hausdorff space with a basis of clopen sets. The class of all zero-dimensional spaces satisfies your property.

Comment: Conversely, if $X$ is a topological space and $Y=(X\times[0,1])/(X\times\{1\})$ is a contractible space, so every retract of $Y$ must also be contractible. However, you can easily select $X$ so that the interiors of the contractible subsets of $Y$ do not form a basis for the topology.

Comment: @JosephVanName The class of zero-dimensional spaces is extremely small; it does not even include smooth manifolds. I'm not sure if the question is reading correctly (because I don't know English very well yet). I mean, I want to find the most general natural class of spaces in which the interiors of the retracts form the base of the topology. It would be great if this is true for all Hausdorff spaces, but I don't believe it. Is the same thing written in my question?

Comment: The English in the question looks fine. By the way, the sentiment that the class of zero-dimensional spaces is ' extremely small' is a matter of perspective. In set theoretic topology or with regards to Stone duality, all spaces that one looks at are zero-dimensional.

Comment: @JosephVanName Yes, of course, this is a matter of perspective. I forget to mention that my perspective is differential and algebraic topology due to the fact that I'm used to reading the relevant forum topics, where everyone assumes this perspective by default.
Thanks for checking my English :)

Comment: @JosephVanName By the way, the zero-dimensionality of the spaces involved in the Stonois duality also depends on the perspective. It seems to me that those mathematicians who are interested in [Stone's duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_duality) as a basis for pointless topology do not associate it with zero-dimensional spaces. But I have not yet studied the pointless topology systematically and I can be very wrong.

Comment: By Stone duality, I was mainly thinking about the duality between compact zero-dimensional spaces and Boolean algebras and similar dualities such as those for Priestley spaces and Esakia spaces. But even in point-free topology, zero-dimensional spaces (especially complete Boolean algebras) play a prominent role. In any case, any further discussion about the relevance of zero-dimensional spaces should be left to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131436/discussion-between-joseph-van-name-and-eschatum-verus).

Answer (score 5):

For a general source of counterexamples: look at connected but not locally connected spaces. The retracts are connected but the neighbourhoods of some points are not.
The [Topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), [Knaster's Bucket Handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_continuum), and the [Pseudoarc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) are well-known examples.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Your example is generalized to "for any property of topological spaces S inherited by quotient spaces, if X is S and r-basic, then X is locally S". It is interesting that for "S = connectedness", "S = linear connectedness" the space splits into a union of subspaces with the property S. Is it true that the connected components inherit this abundance of retracts? If so, then r-basic implies local connectivity, local lin. connectivity, etc.

Comment: By the way, the r-basic Hausdorff space is regular. I wonder if there is a non-metric r-basic Hausdorff space?

Comment: All zero-dimensional spaces, totally ordered sets with the order topology, and arbitrary products of r-basic spaces are r-basic, but these spaces are usually non-metrizable.